# Illustrator - create a shape from big to small with randomness

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I make a random dot placement with gradual size change (and random colors). The overall shape doesn't matter.

Here is an example what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: example]

### Progress so far:

I've managed to make size change with *Object > Blend* but problem with this method is that it isn't random and gaps between lines are different in each row.

[image]

Is there any way to automatize this process or should I just paint it by hand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're nearly there...

Expand and ungroup the pattern that you have created with the blend tool and then go to `Object > Transform > Transform Each...` Select Random in the options and then gradually increase the Horizontal and Vertical Move values. If you turn preview on then you can tweak the values until you get something that you like.

You could also introduce some scaling if you want to mix up the sizes a bit.

Some of the objects will probably end up crashing into each other or looking unevenly distributed so you may have to go in and tidy them up by hand, but this should get you most of the way there.